# Recursive function for game of life wont run in Async

Tags: f#

I am trying to run a function to update a grid for a game of life function written with f# and everything has to be recursive with no mutables. I want to add a pause button to my form by running the Update function asyncronously however when I do this only one square is updated. However when I step through the program without async all of the squares are updated. Any ideas why?

```
let buttonGrid : Button list list = (Startup ar);;

//transform buttongrid to int grid
let rec bg2ig (bg:Button list list) = 
    let rec innerLoop (bl:Button list) =
        match bl with
        |[] -> []
        |x::xs -> if (x.Name = "0") then 0::(innerLoop xs) else 1::(innerLoop xs)
    match bg with
    |[] -> []
    |y::ys -> (innerLoop y)::(bg2ig ys)

let Update (bg:Button list list)=
    let ar = (bg2ig bg)
    let rec innerUpdate (bg:Button list list)= 
        let rec arrayLoop (bl:Button list) y = 
            match bl with
            |[] -> 0
            |x::xs -> 
                let X = (15-xs.Length)
                let n = (neighbors X y ar)
                if  (ar.[X].[y] = 0) then (if n=3 then buttonGrid.[X].[y].Name<-"1") else (if (n=2||n=3)=false then buttonGrid.[X].[y].Name<-"0")
                if buttonGrid.[15-xs.Length].[y].Name="0" 
                then buttonGrid.[15-xs.Length].[y].BackColor <- Color.White 
                else buttonGrid.[15-xs.Length].[y].BackColor <- Color.Black
                arrayLoop xs y
        match bg with
        |[] -> []
        |y::ys -> 
            ignore (arrayLoop y (15-ys.Length)) 
            innerUpdate ys
    innerUpdate bg

let Running = async {
    let rec SubRun (x:int) =
        ignore (Update buttonGrid)
        if x = 1 then
            SubRun 1
        else
            0
    ignore (SubRun 1)
    do! Async.Sleep(1000)
    }

let RunAll() = 
    Running
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
```

Comment: Something is odd about the `SubRun` function. It looks like it will never terminate (with `x` always being 1).

Comment: Yea, I noticed that, I had the sleep there before so that it would wait 1 second before executing Update. The reason why I am looping is to keep my game of life running. I figured I could use a Cancel token to stop the recursive loop but I am unable to figure out why its not working like it should.

Comment: Could be a problem with access to WinForms objects from a non-UI thread. Try to use `Async.StartImmediate` instead of `Async.RunSynchronously`.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomas Petricek solved the initial issue I was having but in order to make things correctly I ended up solving it differently. I think my initial issue may have been stemming from updating the form incorrectly or not at all and thus it looked very wrong.

I ended up writing my async function like this

```
let rec async1(syncContext, form : System.Windows.Forms.Form, cancellationSource:CancellationTokenSource, (limit:int)) =
    async {
        do! Async.SwitchToContext(syncContext)
        ignore (Update buttonGrid)

        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()

        do! Async.Sleep(300)
        if limit > 1 then
            ignore (Async.Start (async1(syncContext, form, cancellationSource, (limit-1)),cancellationSource.Token))
        else if limit = -1 then
            ignore (Async.Start (async1(syncContext, form, cancellationSource, limit),cancellationSource.Token))
    }
```

and then I can call on it like this witha start and stop button

```
let b = new Button(Location=new Point(50,500), Text=("Run"), Width=100, Height=40)
let btnPause = new Button(Location=new Point(150, 500), Text="Stop", Width=100, Height=40, Enabled=false)
b.Click.Add(fun _ -> 
    let cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
    b.Enabled <- false
    btnPause.Enabled <- true
    btnSave.Enabled <- false
    btnLoad.Enabled <- false
    btnStep.Enabled <- false
    inputBox.Enabled <- false
    btnPause.Click.Add(fun _ -> 
        b.Enabled <- true
        btnPause.Enabled <- false
        btnSave.Enabled <- true
        btnLoad.Enabled <- true
        btnStep.Enabled <- true
        inputBox.Enabled <- true
        cancellationSource.Cancel())
    ignore (Async.Start (async1(syncContext, form, cancellationSource, (int inputBox.Text)),cancellationSource.Token))
    ignore (inputBox.Text <- "0"))
```

I have also added a step button for stepping through the program and an input box where I can run the program endlessly until the cancel token is called or have it run through an n number of times and then stop

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, `Async.RunSynchronously` is a wrong function for this scenario. It starts the workflow on a background thread (which is wrong, because you want to access GUI elements) and then it blocks the calling thread until the background work is done (which is wrong because you do not want to block the GUI thread).

You need to use `Async.StartImmediate` which starts the work on the *current thread* (which will be the GUI thread) without blocking. When the first part of the workflow completes (before `Sleep`) the GUI thread is free to do other work. After `Sleep` the workflow will again continue on the GUI thread (this is done automatically thanks to `StartImmediate`) and so you can again access the GUI.

Aside, your `SubRun` function that does the actual looping needs to be asynchronous too - so I'd expect the main part of the loop to look something like this:

```
let Running = async {
    let rec SubRun (x:int) = 
        // Perform update and then sleep before recursive call
        ignore (Update buttonGrid)
        do! Async.Sleep(1000)
        if x = 1 then
            return! SubRun 1
        else
            return 0 }

    // Start the loop and asynchronously ignore the result
    SubRun 1 |> Async.Ignore

let RunAll() = 
    // Start the computation immediately on the current threada
    Running |> Async.StartImmediate
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped med solve my intial issue but in the end I ended up writing the function differently which worked.